# Failed install of Ubuntu 18.04 to Asus GL553VW

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, asus

Does anyone know how to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus [GL553VW](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/GL553VW/0409_E11734_GL553VW_A.pdf) with an [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M GPU](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL553VW/specifications/)? I made a USB, inserted it to the computer, and now the install screen shows only a welcome screen. It looks like English is selected but nothing happens if I press Continue.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what is happening? Is it possible to get into specifics?

Comment: Please advise if you verified the downloaded ISO file you made the LiveUSB with by comparing the file's checksum to the checksum posted at Ubuntu.com . Click [edit] and update your question with that information.  That step eliminates the possibility of corruption during the download and save process.

Answer (score 2):

In your BIOS, please disable Secure Boot and Fast Boot.

When GRUB begins, please tap the letter **e**

Move to the end of the line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** and replace `quiet splash` line with `nouveau.modeset=0`then press [**F10**] to proceed.